# I am a new app developer and I am unsure on how to insert a project from github into my android studio app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, github

So I recently started an android project on android studio and I wanted to use something from github in my project. I watched countless videos but still do not understand. So this is the loading animation I want to use: https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit. In the tutorial, the person is simply copy pasting the Gradle dependency and this :  maven{ url"https://jitpack.io"} in the build.gradle scripts. When I further proceed in my XML file, it is not recognizing when I type out Spinkit, whereas in the video it is. When I go to the class to type in the progress bar code, it is giving me errors that it can't recognize the word ProgressBar. I am very lost so any guidance can help? Thanks for being patient:)

[build.gradle here is where I am typing the maven code thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiRp7.png)

[build.gradle, here is where I am typing the implementation code copy pasted from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHai7.png)

[this is the XML file where I believe is the issue:  the line starting with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkvwX.png)

here is the java class where I am getting the errors

I understand that I am a very inexperienced developer but I just need a little guidance on this issue

Comment: Don't post images of code.

Comment: Please visit this url first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First clear your imports and then reimport Progressbar, Sprite 
.
Then Goto Build -> Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

When you click on that github link, you can find a button that says "Clone or download", click there and download the zip file to the code.
 Unzip it, drag it to the desktop folder for example.

Open AndroidStudio, File, Open, then choose that file.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should sync your project so it can recognize your changes in gradle.
Just above your code it's showing you a message asking you to sync project first.